# Conditional entropy of an outcome

Tags: entropy, information-theory

Given three discrete random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, the conditional entropy

$$ H(X|Y,Z) = \sum_{X}\sum_{Y}\sum_{Z} p(x,y,z) \ \text{log}\frac{p(y,z)}{p(x,y,z)} $$

If I want to calculate the conditional entropy of an outcome $X=x$, is the following equality correct or is the LHS just proportional to the RHS?

$$ H(X=x|Y,Z) = \sum_{X=x}\sum_{Y}\sum_{Z} p(x,y,z) \ \text{log}\frac{p(y,z)}{p(x,y,z)} $$

Comment: Entropy is defined for probability distributions, not individual outcomes. Perhaps you're interested in the [self-information/surprisal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_content)?

Comment: Entropy of $H(X=x|...)$ will be $0$, since there is no uncertainty left over $x$.

Comment: Hmm $p(X=x|...)$ will be a probability distribution so I don't see why entropy would be zero (unless it is for that distribution). Maybe surprisal is useful here.

Comment: Entropy is zero because $X$ can only be $x$, i.e. $X$ is $x$ with probability $1$, leading to no uncertainty, i.e. no entropy.

Comment: Formulas like the one you wrote are indeed used. $H(X=x|Y,Z)$  does not have to be zero (unless $X$ takes only that one value $x$, which I don't think is what you mean). Note that the symbol-wise conditional entropy you propose might not be the only way to define the entropy of a symbol (see for example "How to measure the information gained from one symbol" from DeWesee and related discussions). Note also that $H(X=x|Y,Z)$ unlike $H(X|YZ)$ could be negative.